# Mysql Import Error 1293 Timestamp Issue

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

This has been asked before, but I cannot seem to find a solution that'll work.

I created a database on my localhost server using Mysql, Version information: 4.2.7.1

I have export the .sql file many times and imported it into other localhost servers without any problems.

Now I'm ready to go live, and I am trying to import the .sql file into my hosted server phpMyAdmin.  Version information: 4.3.8, latest stable version: 4.6.4

When I do I get error 1293:

> SQL Error (1293): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one
>   TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause

I have many tables that have the same 2 columns:

date_created which is set to type timestamp, default current_timestamp

last_update which is set to type timestamp, default NULL, on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

This way I can track when a row is added and updated.

How can I change these rows to make the import file work ok?

Comment: Sounds like you are reporting phpMyAdmin version numbers, and not the  MySQL Server version. The behavior (error message) you report is consistent with MySQL 5.5, as documented in the MySQL Reference Manual   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html  Seems like your development environment is using an older version of MySQL, 5.1 or earlier.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, you are right, I did.  

Looks like the development environment is:    Server version: 5.5.51-38.2-log - Percona Server (GPL), Release 38.2, Revision 2

My localhost: Server version: 5.6.20 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Hope that's the correct info.  If that's the case, then my network shouldn't be an issue, correct?

Comment: Yes, MySQL 5.6.x allows for more than one TIMESTAMP column to use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. But MySQL 5.5 does not.